# compare values in different chunks using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, large-data

Say I have in memory a large file, loaded using `chunksize` in pandas. Now I have to compare every value with the ones ajdacent to it. My problem is that I can't seem to select at the same time the extreme values (in first and last position) of two different chunks.
Example:

```
print(df)

     a
0  102
1  101
2  104
3  110
4  104
5  105
```

```
count = 0
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    if df.iloc[i+1]['a']>df.iloc[i]['a']:
        count+=1
```

`count` would be equal to `3` in this example. But say I have loaded `df` from a `.csv` with `chunksize=1`, how would I achieve a similar result, considering that values will be in different chunks? In practice `chunksize` is `10000` and so the problem would be limited to the first and last value for each chunk.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Here is an example where I store the `last_chunk_value` to update the value when running the next loop.
I've tested a 'brut force' method to compare with the 'chunk script'. The results are the same with both methods.
By the way, I've simplified the 'brut force' method.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

# 'data' generation as csv file
file = open("data.csv", 'w')
file.write('rand_int' + '\n')
for i in range(0, 10000):
    file.write(str(random.randint(80,120)) + '\n')
file.close()

# "brute force method"
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
length = int( (df.shift(-1) - df > 0).sum() )
print('number=', length)

# chunksize method
chunksize = 33
length = 0
last_chunk_value = np.nan
for chunk in pd.read_csv("data.csv", chunksize=chunksize):
    chunk['shift'] = chunk.shift(1)
    chunk.iloc[0, 1] = last_chunk_value
    length += (chunk['rand_int'] - chunk['shift'] > 0).sum()
    last_chunk_value = chunk.iloc[-1, 0]

print('number=', length)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think you missed the point of the question: how to access "adjacent" values if they are stored in different chunks.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my first code to provide an answer to your question. Regards !